# Altcoin apps stealing hashes?

Tags: android

It was super cool to discover so many alt coins have cloned the Bitcoin Wallet Android app, however I noticed that the phone started running unusally hot after installing all the coin apps, even when I hadn't opened any since device boot.

After booting my phone (it had been off for a few hours and was cool to the touch) I found that it was running hot after a few minutes.

I  opened the app manager and found that the following coins were running:

Vertcoin (Beta)

Execoin (Beta)

Einsteinium

I remember reading an article about apps that use your phone to steal hashes. http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2613612/Has-battery-life-Android-phone-got-worse-Researchers-warn-rogue-apps-secretly-bitcoin-background.html

Does anyone know if these apps (or any other wallet apps) have any malicious/devious code?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense for the app to be mining the coin that it is a wallet for? Unless the coin (and app) is just a scam, which isn't unlikely.

Comment: Those three coins were running, but which one(s) were using up power?